# Why can't I find myself in the User Reputation Leagues?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

**Move along, nothing to see here... *whistle***

Clicking on the `"Top <x>% this <period>"` link on my SO profile takes me to the relevant page of the User Reputation League for `<period>`. However, if I subsequently change to a different period (say week to month), or even just search for myself on the same page, I get:

```
No users found matching "verdesmarald". Try changing your search above.
```

Why can't I find myself?

Comment: I can find you… Next time spell your name right :P `verdesmarald ` doesn't exist. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vql6g.png

Comment: Wow how embarrassing, it's actually spelt wrong on my profile not in the question, I just never noticed! ><

Comment: If your attention to detail doesn't even extent to the spelling of your name, computers might not be the right career for you.

Comment: @sbi I am up-voting your comment on the assumption you misspelled "extend" on purpose. :)

Comment: @verdesmarald: No, I didn't! I'm a bloody nonnative, and simply failed. `:(` So I again proved that old saying about grammar nazis, and offered an incredible opportunity for you to give me great reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of your spelling mistake!
Instead of [`veredesmarald`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vql6g.png) you tried [`verdesmarald`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhIaH.png).